# ruby thread programming , ruby equivalent of java wait/notify/notifyAll

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading, synchronization

I would like to know what are ruby's alternatives to the Java methods :

- wait
- notify
- notifyAll

Could you please post a small snippet or some links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the caveat that I don't know Java, based on your comments, I think that you want a condition variable.  Google for "Ruby condition variable" comes up with a bunch of useful pages.  The [first link I get](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Threads_and_Processes_Condition_Variables.html), seems to be a nice quick introduction to condition vars in particular, while [this](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_threads.html) looks like it gives a much broader coverage of threaded programming in Ruby.

Comment: It's kinda like Java , except that ruby uses signal and java uses notify. Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is `ConditionVariable` in `Thread`:

```
require "thread"

m = Mutex.new 
c = ConditionVariable.new
t = []

t << Thread.new do
  m.synchronize do
    puts "A - I am in critical region"
    c.wait(m)
    puts "A - Back in critical region"
  end
end

t << Thread.new do
  m.synchronize do
    puts "B - I am critical region now"
    c.signal
    puts "B - I am done with critical region"
  end
end

t.each {|th| th.join }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent to notifyAll(), but the other two are `Thread.stop` (stops the current thread) and `run` (called on a stopped thread to make it start going again).

Comment: I believe ConditionVariable#broadcast is equivalent to notifyAll()

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something more like this.  It'll work on any object instantiated after this gets executed.  It's not perfect, particularly where Thread.stop is outside the mutex.  In java, waiting on a thread, releases a monitor.

```
class Object 
  def wait
    @waiting_threads = [] unless @waiting_threads
    @monitor_mutex = Mutex.new unless @monitor_mutex
    @monitor_mutex.synchronize {
      @waiting_threads << Thread.current
    }
    Thread.stop
  end

  def notify
    if @monitor_mutex and @waiting_threads 
      @monitor_mutex.synchronize {
        @waiting_threads.delete_at(0).run unless @waiting_threads.empty?
      }
    end
  end

  def notify_all
    if @monitor_mutex and @waiting_threads
      @monitor_mutex.synchronize {
        @waiting_threads.each {|thread| thread.run}
        @waiting_threads = []
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `Thread#join`

```
threads = []
10.times do
  threads << Thread.new do
    some_method(:foo)
  end
end

threads.each { |thread| thread.join } #or threads.each(&:join)

puts 'Done with all threads'
```

Comment: Not really. Join waits until a thread finishes execution. Wait pauses a thread until it's notified , so that it can resume execution.

Comment: Ah.  My bad.  I don't actually know Java so my wild guess failed.