# Ruby Wait and Signal

Tags: ruby

I have **two threads** in a ruby process. What I want to do is have **one sleep** and the **other send a signal** to wake up.

I know how to do it with Mutex and ConditionalVariables, but I don't have a critic section to run so it's not the right solution.

I know how to do it with thread stop and thread run, where on thread stops itself and the other calls run on it, but It's now what I'm really looking for.

Is there other way? What I'm trying to accomplish is have on thread wait for content in the database and the other notify when there is content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534919/ruby-thread-programming-ruby-equivalent-of-java-wait-notify-notifyall gives rundown and example of how to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Heineken what's wrong with the Mutex/CondVar approach? Even when you have a boolean predicate (data/no data), accessing the predicate should be done under the protection of a mutex.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone with the Mutex/CondVar approach. I tought I could get something just like queue and signal like I have in java but couldn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
require "thread"

q = Queue.new

Thread.new do
  sleep 10
  q.push "*"
end

p q.pop
```